# Form: Validate special cases with jQuery before form submission

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, validation

I need to validate a form without using any special plugin, just jQuery.

I have a disabled SUBMIT button which I am enabling like this:

```js
const getFields = $(
  'form#inquiry-component-form input, form#inquiry-component-form textarea, form#inquiry-component-form select'
).filter('[required]:visible');

getFields.on('input', () => {

  let empty = false;

  getFields.each(function() {
    if (!empty && $(this).val() == '') {
      empty = true;
    }
  });

  $('#submit-inquiry-form').prop('disabled', empty);
});
```

The problem I am having is that the form contains a phone number and email address inputs, so the submit button will become enabled when those 2 inputs are not empty anymore. I need them to match the pattern first, then the submit button gets enabled.

These are the tel and email inputs:

```html
<input id="inquiry-phone" class="form-control" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number (10 digits)" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required>
<input id="inquiry-email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. I added a submit button and then we're checking to enable the button or not using regex.

```html
<form id="submit-inquiry-form">
  <input id="inquiry-phone" class="form-control" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number (10 digits)" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required>
  <input id="inquiry-email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
  <button id="btn" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
const getFields = $(
  'input'
).filter('[required]:visible');

getFields.on('input', () => {
  let empty = false;
  let patternMatch = true;
  
  getFields.each(function() {
    console.log("check", $(this).val())
    if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
      empty = true;
    }
    
    // check for regex
    if ($(this).attr("pattern")) {
      const regex = new RegExp($(this).attr("pattern"));
      patternMatch = regex.test($(this).val())
    }
  });
  
  if (empty || !patternMatch) {
    console.log("empty or bad match")
    $('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: But here you are not validating email input.

Comment: @Reacting - for email validation the code will still work. you would just need to provide a "pattern" attribute for email like you did for phone. The pattern can be an email validation Regex like `[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}` or another one if you'd like.